# Why this function is able to validate user input without using Validator class?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I am studying a [Laravel application](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) and I found some strange behaviour in this application.

There are a few web forms in this application. Most of the controller methods that handle POST requests use `Validator::make()` to validate user input, but I found 2 methods which do not use `Validator::make()` at all.

At first I thought there are no input validation in these 2 forms. However, surprisingly, I found that the web forms are still able to validate the user input.

**Example 1:**
(using Validator)

1. [Controller Method 1](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/5581a48a21bcc40356aa97b06dce7a95f1c262c4/app/controllers/admin/AdminBlogsController.php) (Line 60 - 67)
2. [Controller Method 2](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/5581a48a21bcc40356aa97b06dce7a95f1c262c4/app/controllers/admin/AdminCommentsController.php) (Line 62 - 68)

---

```
$rules = array(
    'title'   => 'required|min:3',
    'content' => 'required|min:3'
);
...
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

---

**Example 2:**
(Not using Validator)

1. [Controller Method 3](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/57a7a4a0ffda1f444e6ec9eb24b89cfa3092c8bb/app/controllers/admin/AdminUsersController.php) (Line 89 - 111)
2. [Controller Method 4](https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/57a7a4a0ffda1f444e6ec9eb24b89cfa3092c8bb/app/models/UserRepository.php) (Line 27 - 47)

---

```
$this->user->username = Input::get( 'username' );
$this->user->email = Input::get( 'email' );
$this->user->password = Input::get( 'password' );
...
$this->user->save();
```

---

I would like to know why the functions in **Example 2** are able to validate user input without using `Validator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user model of this application uses the `ConfideUser` trait. If we take a look at that [trait in the confide package](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/blob/master/src/Confide/ConfideUser.php) we can see that there's a `save()` method that overrides the default one from Laravel.

```
/**
 * Overwrites the original save method in order to perform
 * validation before actually saving the object.
 *
 * @param array $options
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    if ($this->isValid()) {
        return parent::save($options);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It will call `$this->isValid()` and only save if everything is alright. And here's `isValid()`:

```
/**
 * Checks if the current user is valid using the ConfideUserValidator.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isValid()
{
    // Instantiate the Zizaco\Confide\UserValidator and calls the
    // validate method. Feel free to use your own validation
    // class.
    $validator = App::make('confide.user_validator');
    // If the model already exists in the database we call validate with
    // the update ruleset
    if ($this->exists) {
        return $validator->validate($this, 'update');
    }
    return $validator->validate($this);
}
```

It makes an instance of confide's own `UserValidator` and uses that to validate the current model.